# JustMock: How to assert Method <T> (Action<T> a)

Tags: justmock

I am using `JustMock` and `NServiceBus`.

I want to assert that following statement is executed once:

```
 _bus.Publish<ISpecialEvent>(x =>
                {
                    x.Prop1= "Very special";                    
                });
```

so that's what I am using:

```
void Publish<T>(Action<T> messageConstructor);
```

Now I am mocking `NServiceBus`:

```
 var serviceBus = Mock.Create<IBus>();
```

and assert:

```
 Mock.Assert(() => serviceBus.Publish(Arg.IsAny<ISpecialEvent>()), Occurs.Once());
```

Well obviously this won't work as this does match the actual usage of `.Publish`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

it can be done like this:
Publish(Arg.IsAny>())